# how to create img tag using src from database in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, image, tags

I am doing an application web asp.net mvc and I want to know what is the best way to generate img tag with value of the attribute src coming from a database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Get it from the db

Step 2:
Put the information in a viewmodel that could be formatted like this one:

```
public class ExampleViewModel {
    public string ImageSrc {get; set; }
}
```

Step 3:
Bind this viewmodel to a page using the @model ExampleViewModel on top of the screen

Step 4:
Bind the attribute to your image tag:

```
<img src="@Model.ImageSrc" alt="image" />
```

This should work